# Xcode 5 bots and Testflight automated builds

Tags: ios, xcode5, testflight, xcode-bots

First I have a Mac Mini running Server on Mavericks and have Xcode 5 installed. On the server I have my iOS projects set up with Bots to run automated builds of my Github repo on each commit to master. What I want to find out is if anyone already has configure this kind of setup to work with automated builds being sent to TestFlight.

The script that worked previously with a Jenkins build process is pasted below, but throws an error and doesn't upload when the bot completes it's build. I have this script run on the "post-action" of the archive process of my app.

Server log error:

> Print: Entry, "CFBundleVersion", Does Not Exist
>
> error: Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : '/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Cache/s892fj1n2-f4bb-2514-522v-2a23d0f0c725/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.ipa'

Script:

```
 PLIST_FILE=$(echo -n "${SRCROOT}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
 BUILD_TYPE=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PLIST_FILE}")
 API_TOKEN="<API_TOKEN>"
 TEAM_TOKEN="<SECRET>"

 APP="${BUILD_ROOT}/Debug-iphoneos/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}"

/bin/rm "/bots/${PRODUCT_NAME}.ipa"
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${APP}" -o "/bots/${PRODUCT_NAME}.ipa"

/usr/bin/curl "http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json" \
-F file=@"/bots/${PRODUCT_NAME}.ipa" \
-F a      pi_token="${API_TOKEN}" \
-F team_token="${TEAM_TOKEN}" \
-F notes="Build uploaded automatically from server." \
-F distribution_lists="internal"
```

**UPDATE 11/20:**

A good resource to try:
[TestFlight Bots](http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/)

I didn't get it to work a couple weeks ago but the post has been updated since I last tried.

Comment: There is way too much discussion about TestFlight on this thread. The problem has nothing to do with TestFlight and everything to do with the error the xcrun process created: Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for Xcode 6

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions issue. Are you able to access \Library\XCode\Data folder? I was able to run your script (other than upload to testflight). I had to give read access to \Data and write access to destination folder and I see the ipa created.

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test this yet, I'll let you know if that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: And almost a month later... That didn't completely fix it, but it did help. I still can't get the TestFlight build to upload but I did find another good resource (added link to my original post).

Answer (score 0):

I am researching ways to switch my team from our Jenkins farm for iOS builds to the new Xcode bots server.  I have a very similar problem to solve regarding continuous deployment upon a successful CI build/test.

I don't have an answer (yet), but, wanted to share some things I found that may help you.

Two threads may help give clues to why your TestFlight upload is failing on the bots server.

According to Kra Larivain with [this post regarding the CocoaPods CLI and Xcode bots](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cocoapods/eYL8QB3XjyQ/n-Ug12V0wb8J):

- "the build runs on the bot as an unprivileged user with no shell (_teamsserver with /usr/bin/false as a shell)"
- "add `_teamsserver` to the password-less sudoers (`%_teamsserver  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in your sudoers file). You probably want to be a little bit more clever and only grant it sudo privilege" for the commands actually needed
- `/Library/Server/Xcode/Data` is set to be rw by the `_teamsserver` user only
- "add to your pre action the following script, where `BUILD_USER` is your, well, build user. Make sure you `Provide build settings from` the main target, `SRCROOT` won’t be set otherwise (the default is `None`)." *This example is for CocoaPods, but, could be adapted to your use*

```sh
if [ `whoami` = '_teamsserver' ]; then
echo "running pod install as part of CI build"
chmod 777 /Library/Server/Xcode/Data
cd ${SRCROOT}
rm ./Podfile.lock
rm -rf ./Pods
sudo chown -R BUILD_USER .
sudo -H -u BUILD_USER pod install
sudo chown -R _teamsserver .
fi
```

You likely seen this already, but, it's worth mentioning for others.  Check Justin Miller's [post on Xcode and testflight post-archive actions](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2011/sep/02/automating-development-uploads-testflight-xcode/) for comparison with your script.

Good luck!
Steve

Comment: I did see this post before, I'm going to try to get this started again. I added a link to the original post that may help as well. I'll post back with what works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark, any progress? I'm new to CI and have been running into the same issues with projects with Cocoapods.

Comment: @EdGs I worked on it for some time and eventually went back to using Jenkins for the time being, I just couldn't get the TestFlight builds to upload. The best thing (I think) that I tried was [this link](http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/). On a side note, Apple did recently acquire Burstly (the company that owns TestFlight) [source](http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/21/rumor-testflight-owner-burstly-is-being-acquired-by-apple/), so maybe we will see some integration with Xcode Server in the near future.

Comment: "add to your pre action the following script, where BUILD_USER is your, well, build user"

Do you need to set up this somewhere?